# How to join table with itself using another table in hibernate with annotations?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, many-to-many

I have two tables - users and friends.
Any user may have any number of friends (another users). These relationships are stored in a table 'friends', so this is just service table.

[Pricture of relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAZWv.png)

How should I code this in my entity classes? Should I use @ManyToMany?
My presumption is the next:

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "friends",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "sender") }
    )
    private Set<User> friendsInviters = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<User> friendsReceiver = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Friend.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "friends")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Friend implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "sender")
    private Long sender;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "receiver")
    private Long receiver;

}
```

P.S. - i just started to learn Hibernate:)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name="users_friends",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "friend_id") }
    )
    private Set<User> friendsInviters = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "friendsInviters")
    private Set<User> friendsReceiver = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<User> getFriendsInviters() {
        return friendsInviters;
    }

    public void setFriendsInviters(Set<User> friendsInviters) {
        this.friendsInviters = friendsInviters;
    }

    public Set<User> getFriendsReceiver() {
        return friendsReceiver;
    }

    public void setFriendsReceiver(Set<User> friendsReceiver) {
        this.friendsReceiver = friendsReceiver;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this will work for  your problem

Comment: this will create two table one is user and user_friend for mapping relation